# React Stripe Elements & SSR - Webpack Error: Window is Not Defined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, stripe-payments

React Stripe Elements works fine in development but deploying live via Netlify throws 'Webpack: Window is undefined' in Provider.js react stripe elements node module file.

As per some other suggestions I have tried ComponentDidMount method and also editing the Provider.js with this:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    let iInnerHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Both still result in failed deploys.

Also, I have tried setting stripe or apiKey in StripeProvider component, setting stripe throws error requiring Stripe object, e.g. Stripe(...) --> when switched with this get Stripe is not defined and apiKey throws window undefined error.

This is my gatsby-ssr.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ShopkitProvider } from './src/shopkit'
import { StripeProvider, Elements } from 'react-stripe-elements'
import Layout from './src/components/Layout'

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
      <StripeProvider apiKey={process.env.GATSBY_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
          <ShopkitProvider clientId{process.env.GATSBY_MOLTIN_CLIENT_ID}>
              <Elements>{element}</Elements> 
          </ShopkitProvider>
      </StripeProvider>
  )
}

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
    return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
}
```

Everything is working as expected on development, but SSR present window undefined issue with Webpack. I have also set env variables in Netlify as well in .env file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there's a check for Stripe object in `window` inside `StripeProvider`. This means you can't use it raw in `wrapRootElement`. The simple solution is to not use `StripeProvider` in `gatsby-ssr.js`, you only need it in `gatsby-browser.js`.

---

However, since you're wrapping the root with multiple service providers, and also if you're loading Stripe asynchronously like this:

```
// somewhere else                                      vvvvv
<script id="stripe-js" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" async />
```

You might as well make a common wrapper that can be used in both `gatsby-ssr` & `gatsby-browser` so it's easier to maintain.

I did this by creating a wrapper for `StripeProvider` where `Stripe` is manually initiated depending on the availability of `window` & `window.Stripe`. Then the `stripe` instance is passed as a prop to `StripeProvider` instead of an api key.

```
// pseudo
const StripeWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  let stripe,
  if (no window) stripe = null
  if (window.Stripe) stripe = window.Stripe(...)
  else {
    stripeLoadingScript.onload = () => window.Stripe(...)
  }
  return (
    <StripeProvider stripe={stripe}>
      {children}
    <StripeProvider>
  )
}
```

This logic should be put in a `componentDidMount` or a `useEffect` hook. Here's an example with hook:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { StripeProvider } from 'react-stripe-elements'

const StripeWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const [ stripe, setStripe ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // for SSR
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') return

    // for browser
    if (window.Stripe) {
      setStripe(window.Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY))
    } else {
      const stripeScript = document.querySelector('#stripe-js')
      stripeScript.onload = () => {
        setStripe(window.Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY))
      }
    }
  }, []) // <-- passing in an empty array since I only want to run this hook once

  return (
    <StripeProvider stripe={stripe}>
      {children}
    </StripeProvider>
  )
}

// export a `wrapWithStripe` function that can used
// in both gatsby-ssr.js and gatsby-browser.js
const wrapWithStripe = ({ element }) => (
  <StripeWrapper>
    <OtherServiceProvider>
      {element}
    </OtherServiceProvider>
  </StripeWrapper>
)
```

Comment: Derek - thanks for taking the time to post this. Just reran a build and worked like a charm. Now I can finally deploy after going round in circles for a few days. Cheers

Comment: @DominickTaylor NP & welcome to stackoverflow! If the answer works for you, please mark it as correct so it can be served as a reference later on -- you'll earn a little points for following the site's rule as well. Here's [more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/433191)

Answer (score 1):

By setting async to **true** in gatsby-config.js

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-stripe`,
  options: {
    async: true
  }
}
```

It is possible to simplify the code above.

```js
const Stripe = props => {
    const [stripe, setStripe] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const obj = await window.Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);
      setStripe(obj);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <StripeProvider stripe={stripe}>
         {children}
      </StripeProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```